# Calling Fortran intrinsics in gdb

Tags: fortran, gdb

How can I call Fortran intrinsics from within gdb? For example, given an array, I want to do

```
call size(array)
```

but I get `No symbol "size" in current context.` Is it necessary to define them in gdb first, or is there some way of calling them directly?

Answer (score 3):

Intrinsics are implemented by compiler in some vendor specific library. For example, Intel compiler implements size intrinsic by inlined code, that placed stored array length to a given variable, and as a result there is no function that can be called.

Technically, GDB/IILDB can evaluate any function implemented in given binary file (you can find all of them using **nm** utility on most of the Unix based systems). For example, if program defines following function:

```
function get_pi() result(pi)
    real pi

     pi = 3.1415926
end function
```

it's possible to invoke it by following statement in debugger:

```
p (float) get_pi()
```

Please keep in mind, that real name of this function (provided by nm) will be different. Usually it starts and ends by underscore character, like '_gdb_array_module_mp_**get_pi**_'.

But you are always is able to use any functions from core C library, like **size** that returns amount of memory allocated for a given variable. And to determine array size in Fortran program it's possible to use following statement:

```
p sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)
```

Comment: So does that mean that you cannot call intrinsic functions like `maxval` or `minval`.
Also, would you mind elaborating your comment about "core C library"? I suspect that means libc, `<math.h>` is in libc so with that logic we should be able to call from GDB `sin(x)` but that does not seem to be the case.